# How to add a param to a URL that trigger jQuery to run a function on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is there a way to add a url param like: http://site.com?open=true

And on document ready, if jQuery sees the open param set to true execute a function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first lets make a good Query string searcher in JS

```
function querySt(qsName, url)
        {
            var theUrl;
            if (url == null || url == undefined)
                theUrl = window.location.search.substring(1); else theUrl = url;
            var g = theUrl.split("&");
            for (var i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
                var pair = g[i].split("=");
                if (pair[0].toLowerCase() == qsName.toLowerCase())
                {
                    return pair[1];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }



$(function (){
  if (querySt("open")!='true') return;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

taken from website http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/06/10/reading-get-variables-with-javascript/

> ```
> function $_GET(q,s) { 
>     s = s ? s : window.location.search; 
>     var re = new RegExp('&'+q+'(?:=([^&]*))?(?=&|$)','i'); 
>     return (s=s.replace(/^?/,'&').match(re)) ? (typeof s[1] == 'undefined' ? '' : decodeURIComponent(s[1])) : undefined; 
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can test `location.href` with a regex:

```
if (location.href.match(/open=true/)
    // do something
```

You might want to work on the regex though, to make sure it works for you.